# Is a POST request sent over multiple chunks?

Tags: node.js, http, post, server, get

I was doing some nodejs and I ran into a scenario in which I had to use POST requests. I saw that node deals with POST requests in a slightly different manner than the GET requests. In the case of POST requests we need to create two event listeners `on('data', ...)` and `on('end', ...)` . In the case of GET requests, I found no such complication. All of this led me to believe that maybe GET requests are always guaranteed to be sent within one chunk of data from the client. Whereas, POST requests can be sent over multiple chunks. Am I correct, or is there any flaw in my understanding. Please correct me if so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GET requests don't usually have a "body" as part of them so once you've read the http request headers, you have everything so there is no need for additional code to read more.

POST requests, on the other hand, usually do have a body so once you've gotten the headers, you then need to read the body.

FYI, TCP is a streaming protocol which means there are no guarantees about what chunks data will arrive in.  Even the headers themselves could arrive in multiple packets.  But, the http library you're using already takes care of that for you.   It reads data until it has all the headers.  Reading the body of a POST request is more up to you to do unless you use some sort of body-parser middleware which will read the body for you.

Comment: So, how does the server know whether the header has ended or it should still wait for more packets that would contain the remainder of the header. Is there any kind of a header length field, just like a Content-Length field

Comment: @ShayakSarkar - HTTP headers end with this sequence `<CR><LF><CR><LF>` (double carriage return/line feed which signify end of one line and then a blank line).  So, the incoming data is read until that sequence is found and that signifies the end of the headers.